# How to manage 'Distance from Text' with addImage in phpWord

Tags: phpword

I am using the following:

```
$imageStyle = [
    'width' => 88,
    'marginLeft' => 0,
    'marginTop' => 0,
    'wrappingStyle' => 'square',
    'positioning' => 'absolute',
];

$table->addCell()->addImage('my-image.png', $imageStyle);
```

When I view my generated document in Microsoft Word, and open the images 'Size and Position' dialog box, and then press the 'Text Wrapping' button, I see that my Image's Wrapping Style is Square (which is desired, and per my style settings).

However, there is a "Wrap Text" section which is set to "Both sides", and "Distance from Text'" is set to Top: 0cm, Left: 0.32cm, Bottom: 0cm and Right: 0.32cm.

I didn't set these values, and I cannot determine how to change them with phpWord.

Does anyone have any tips on how to control these "Distance from Text" values?

Answer (score 0):

This has been implemented in the latest development branch.
To use it add a dependency to version `dev-develop`

It will be included in version 0.15